iOS: Left bar button in navbar flashing when navigating back
I'm customizing the navbar and their bar buttons with a custom font using this code
let textAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: AppTheme.ptsansMedium(withSize: 17.0), NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: currentTheme.mainColor ]

UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(textAttributes, for: .normal)
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(textAttributes, for: .focused)
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(textAttributes, for: .highlighted)

I use this code in AppDelegateand didFinishLaunchingWithOptions function.
When running the app, pushing a view controller, and then returning, the default font briefly appears before the custom font is restored.

What am I missing?

Where do you call those? UIAppearance docs starts with a note stating iOS applies appearance changes when a view enters a window, but it doesn’t change the appearance of a view that’s already in a window. To change the appearance of a view that’s currently in a window, remove the view from the view hierarchy and then put it back. Simply put, call it from your AppDelegate

I call this in AppDelegate and didFinishLaunchingWithOptions. Is there a specific method I should move this over?

No that I would do as well. I used your code replacing color and font, but couldn't reproduce the error. There may be something else trying to manipulate the bar button.
